# External drive does not show as mounted but shows up in root filesystem

Tags: linux, mount, external-hdd

So I am running Linux Mint with the following:

- One external drive plugged directly into a USB 3.0 port
- An external drive bay with two HDDs (one in each available slot)

I have my fstab with the following:

```
# Passport is the external drive connected directly
UUID=7e519cb9-3714-4426-932a-f4fc249037f0 /media/passport   ext4 defaults,nofail  0    0

# Bullet is one of the drives in the external bay
UUID=6f7a7259-ecf1-437e-bf82-afc6f9d055c4 /media/bullet   ext4 defaults,nofail  0    0
```

If I do a df, I only see passport as mounted:

```
$ df -h | egrep "passport|bullet"
/dev/sdb1       1.8T   36G  1.7T   3% /media/passport
```

But I can navigate/ls  `/media/bullet`:

```
$ ls -ltr /media/bullet | wc -l
8
```

Not sure how this happened as I was under the impression that mounts should be "separate" from the root file system but it shows up when I do a `du`:

```
$ du -kx / | sort -n | grep bullet | tail -1
2657956 /media/bullet
```

Any thoughts on how this happened and how to resolve it?

EDIT with some additional details:

- My BIOS has external drives as the primary for boot order
- Because of the above, I powered down/unplugged the drives when I rebooted
- I thinks plugged everything in after power up
- and ran `sudo mount -a`

EDIT2: So I did the following:

- Shutdown the machine
- Unplugged both the external drive and turned off the HDD bay
- Booted up
- Saw that neither drive was there in a `df`
- Plugged in the external drive
- It auto mounted in the right place and as a separate drive
- Turned on the HDD bay
- Same scenario as before where the files appear as part of the root file system
- Doing a `df` or `sudo fdisk -l` doesn't even how the drive
- It's almost as though the server thinks the drive is integral to the machine
- Another drive in the HDD bay shows up as a regular drive which is even more confusing

Comment: What does the explicit output of `ls /media/bullet` show? Any unusual files?

Comment: Maybe it's just data you put there when `/media/bullet` was not mounted yet and it's a non-empty directory?

Comment: @AdminBee it shows the files I would expect to see.

Comment: Then I would assume my below answer is correct, and whatever program wrote the files did so "without knowing" that your external HDD was not yet attached ...

Comment: @adminbee added some more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is not necessarily surprising or indicator of a serious fault. In Linux, a mount point is first and foremost a directory on the root file system, an can be used as such without restrictions (subject of course to the usual access permissions).

The special meaning of mount point arises when you actually attach a file system to it using the `mount` command. Anything written to the directory *before* it was a mount point is then shadowed by the content of the external filesystem attached to it, but will become accessible again once the external filesystem is unmounted.

So, the fact that files reside in `/media/bullet` without your external HDD attached is possibly the result of some program writing to that directory at a moment when the filesystem you wanted to mount there was not yet mounted. You can simply delete or move these files out of the way, and continue using the directory as a mount point as you originally intended.

Comment: So the HDD is attached (although it was powered on after startup since my BIOS has external USB as first in the boot order).

I should add that I ran a "sudo mount -a" after startup expecting everything to "work"